# C# ParseExact Exception

Tags: c#

I am about to go nuts

```
        var date1 = "Jun 24 13:07:0 2021";
        var date2 = "May 24 13:07:0 2021";
        try
        {
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
            date1,
            new string[] { "MMMM dd HH:mm:s yyyy", "MMMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" },
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Suceess!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{e}");

        }
```

date2 works while date1 fails with exception !!!
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MMMM` format specifier is full month names ("January", "February", etc.), you probably want `MMM` for abbreviated month names ("Jan", "Feb", etc.) - `date2` works because "May" is the same whether in full or abbreviated.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
new string[] { "MMM dd HH:mm:s yyyy", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" }
```

instead of

```
new string[] { "MMMM dd HH:mm:s yyyy", "MMMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" }
```